# UIlabel linebreak with scrollview not correctly display if too long (iphone retina simulator)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview, uilabel

i have UIlabel using below code, i don't know maybe its too long or not. but when it is scrolled, the uilabel get this result. How can i solve the problem? are there any limitation using uilabel?

[image: Picture]

```
CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(100,9999);
CGSize expectedLabelSize = [summaryBlogParsed sizeWithFont: contentSummaryLabel.font 
                                         constrainedToSize:maximumLabelSize 
                                             lineBreakMode: contentSummaryLabel.lineBreakMode]; 

//adjust the label the the new height.
CGRect newFrame = contentSummaryLabel.frame;
newFrame.size.height = expectedLabelSize.height;
contentSummaryLabel.frame = newFrame;
contentSummaryLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
contentSummaryLabel.text = summaryBlogParsed;

[contentSummaryLabel sizeToFit];
contentScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width*2 + CGRectGetMaxY(contentSummaryLabel.frame));
```

Edit:
This problem occur when i use Iphone Retina simulator.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like labels overlaying on top of each other. You can try setting their `backgroundColour` to `[UIColor clearColor]` and their `opaque` property to `NO` to check that it is indeed the case. If it is then you will have to check your frame setting code.

If the whole thing is one label then you probably don't want a single label with so many lines, but you can try calling `setNeedsDisplay` to force redrawing.

Comment: my problem only happen in iPhone Retina simulator (not yet try in real device). if i use non-retina iphone simulator its fine. I also tried the clear color and opaque to NO but still have the problem.If use clear color, it will become blank (white, no drawing). WHere do i need to put setNeedsDisplay?

Comment: maybe in scrollviewdidscroll delegate, is it one label for the whole thing? If so I think you should use a UITextView or do the text drawing in core graphics if you need different fonts.

Comment: the November 11 (date) and the summary (below date label) is different label. I do not need different fonts. I do not want to use UITextView because it is a subclass of UiScrollView, I implemented uitextview earlier but part the text just cut off, that is why i choose UILabel.I call setNeedsdisplay from my label but it is not working and it makes my app laggy when scrolling.